# shared data between threads synchronized using std::atomic

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I have producer and consumer threads, 1 each. both have to share some data(can be some user defined class's object). I want to use c++ 11 std::atomic to synchronize the access, so that if consumer comes to read while producer is writing to the shared data, consumer waits for producer to finish.

please review the code and give your comments if the code below can achieve this. you can assume producer and consumer threads are calling set and get on SharedData class's object which was initialized with some data object.

Thanks for your time and valuable inputs.

```
template <typename T>
class SharedData
{
    static const int SD_BUSY = 0x01;
    static const int SD_FREE = 0x02;
    typedef std::atomic<int> AtomicInt;

    struct AcqRel
    {
        AtomicInt& _atomInt;
        AcqRel(AtomicInt& atomInt) :_atomInt(atomInt)
        {
            int expectedValue = SharedData::SD_FREE;
            do
            {
                expectedValue = SharedData::SD_FREE;
            } while (!_atomInt.compare_exchange_strong(expectedValue, SharedData::SD_BUSY));
        }

        ~AcqRel()
        {
            _atomInt.store(SharedData::SD_FREE);
        }
    };

    AtomicInt _atomInt = SD_FREE;
    T _data;

public:
    void set(T& data)
    {
        AcqRel al(_atomInt);
        _data = data;
    }

    void get(T& data)
    {
        AcqRel al(_atomInt);
        data = _data;
    }
};
```

Please suggest a lock free method to achieve what I tried above. I want to share data between threads by some lock free method.

Comment: Why use a `std::atomic` for mutual exclusion instead of a `std::mutex`? Naive spinlock implementations like this have horrible behavior under contention.

Comment: std::atomic is not compulsory but any other lock free method will do. I know std::mutex is a better suit for this  requirement but i dont want to use locks. Can you suggest a better method or point out mistakes in my implementation.

Comment: From Stroustrup's "The C++ programming language": Prefer a mutex over an atomic for anything but simple counters and the like".

Comment: Your core `do`/`while` loop makes two *huge* mistakes. First, it can be a resource hog, saturating the FSB on some CPUs and starving the other thread in the physical core on some CPUs. This is terrible because it can starve the thread that needs to release! Second, when you finally do acquire, and it's critical that you run as quickly as possible so you can release, you take the worst imaginable mis-predicted branch and basically destroy the pipelines. Bluntly, it looks like performance was not really considered in the design of this code.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation looks correct, meaning that it doesn't have data races and it provides desired data protection. But as Casey already commented, you effectively try to mimic mutex behaviour. And your implementation is less efficient, so no point to do that. After all, despite the name `AcqRel`, that class actually employs default `memory_seq_cst` semantics. It's better to really use acquire/release here (although `std::mutex` is even better).

Comment: By saying that i have used the default memory_seq_cst do you mean that it is actually using the OS mutex objects internally??

Comment: @anandsrivastava No, employing `memory_seq_cst` is about memory consistency i.e. consistent ordering of the statements around the atomic object.

Comment: @anandsrivastava The standard allows an implementation of `std::atomic` to use an underlying mutex. You can check if `std::atomic` is implemented lock-free using [`std::atomic::is_lock_free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).